# Why am I getting a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'bool'" error?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, boolean, decimal, if-statement

I want to hide some things when the value of the numericUpDown is changed so I wrote this:

```
if (numericUpDown1.Value = 1)
{
    Label1.Hide();
}
```

but I get this error message:

> ***Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'bool'***

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 9):

I think you mean "`if (numericUpDown1.Value == 1)`".

In most languages, "`==`" is the test for equality, while "`=`" is the assignment operator.

Comment: more evidence of a facepalm tag required :)

Answer (score 2):

You're not performing a comparison (change **= to ==**) ... Try:

```
if (numericUpDown1.Value == 1)
{
    Label1.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What language are you using with the single "=" sign?  In VB you would be comparing and in C# you would be assigning a number with an "if" statement.  A way to protect yourself from this would be to list the number first:  if (1 = numericUpDown) which would be fine if comparing was allowed in that language and bad you had intended to make an assignment.  The mistake would jump out at you!